# PyWin32 module not found after installing pywin32 for python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

Hi I am trying to send an image to a printer via python but when I imported win32ui , win32gui and win32con it said that win32ui module was not found but I have already installed the latest version of pywin32.

```
import win32ui
from win32 import win32gui
import win32con
from PIL import Image, ImageWin
```

The code looks good to me so why???

Comment: If the `win32ui` module isn't found, it likely means it's not installed. Did you download a version for Python 3 (verses one for Python 2)? Did it install without errors? Also make sure you have the most current version. The website is https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32